# Не заполняются элементы vector

Tags: c++, vector

В последнем цикле элементы не выводятся. Пробовала выводить по отдельности - они пустые.

````
    cout << "Enter amount of the students: ";
    cin >> students_amount;
    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

    vector<string> students_names(students_amount);

    for(int i = 0; i < students_amount; i++){
        string name;

        cout << "Enter " << i+1 << "th student name: ";
        getline(cin, name);

        students_names.push_back(name);
    }

    cout << "Students list: " << endl;
    for(int i; i < students_amount; i++){
        cout << students_names[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;```
````

Comment: `vector<string> students_names{}; students_names.reserve(students_amount);` А то сейчас у вас сразу создается `students_amount` пустых записей.

Comment: тогда выводит ошибку:
[Error] in C++98 'students_names' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Comment: а зачем в 2020 использовать С++98? используйте хотя бы с++17

Comment: из-за версии ошибка получается?

Comment: @user7860670, для поддержки легаси вестимо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пишете

```
vector<string> students_names(students_amount);
```

то заполняйте как

```
students_names[i] =  name;
```

Или, если `push_back`, то

```
vector<string> students_names;
```

`push_back` дополняет вектор новыми элементами.

Comment: спасибо, так получается